Creating new layer that shows the number of intersecting vector layers at each point in QGIS
I have a QGIS project file with over 50 layers, each representing a different species' habitat range.
I would like to create a new layer that adds up the number of layers at each point in the map and returns a new overlay on the map that shows the number of species that overlap for each point. See these images as an example: https://ibb.co/album/Qr27r3
See representation below:



What if polygons in one layer intersects other polygons in the same layer, should they count as one or multiple?

What should I do when someone answers my question?

You can try the overlap analysis algorithm:


If your data is in the form of points then you can use the "Count Point in Polygon" tool under the "Analysis Tools" in the "Vector" menu.


I have three polygon layers:

Workflow:

Merge all layers into one'
Union the output layer with itself as input layer, no overlay layer
Aggregate the union:



If you don't want to count internal overlaps in one layer your should Dissolve each layer first with option "Keep disjoint features separate" true.

I think you need to:

Merge all your layers using "Merge Vector Layers."
Prepare your points that you want to get statistics .
Run spatial join with "Join by attribute location (summary)" (Use count as summarize field.)
Number of layers in specific points will be shown in the attribute table of the output


Let's assume there is a polygon vector layer called 'Polygons', see the image below.

Step 1. Install the "QGIS Resource Sharing" plugin. ⚠️ Keep in mind, that it is an experimental plugin

Step 2. Open the plugin via its logo, find the "Polygon Tools", and install this tool. Afterwards, two models will be added to the Processing Toolbox (Ctrl+Alt+T)

Step 3. Apply the "Count Polygon Overlap" model with a desired input layer

and get the output like this


References:

QGIS Resource Sharing - Documentation

